# Bash Array Help and Advice

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, while-loop, shift

I have an array that consists of the following: -

```
d23 d3 d21 d1 d20 d0 d26 d6
```

I want to repeat the same for every two elements of the array.  For example:

```
echo d23 d3
```

And then move on to the next two elements:

```
echo d21 d1
```

I've attempted a combination of while loops and shift to avail.  Any help and advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation of [ooga's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784505/3776858) with recursion:

```
a=(d23 d3 d21 d1 d20 d0 d26 d6)
pp () 
{ 
  [ $# -lt 2 ] && return
  echo $1 $2
  shift 2
  pp $@
}

pp "${a[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just loop through them:

```
a=(d23 d3 d21 d1 d20 d0 d26 d6)

$ echo ${#a[@]}
8

$ for (( i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=2 )); do echo "${a[$i]} ${a[$i+1]}"; done
d23 d3
d21 d1
d20 d0
d26 d6
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your heart set on using `shift` note that it only works on the positional parameters, so you could use it in a function:

```
print_pairs () {
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        echo $1 $2;
        shift 2;
    done
}

a=(d23 d3 d21 d1 d20 d0 d26 d6)
print_pairs "${a[@]}"
```